# Flask with QtWebBrowser. Error with opening file

Tags: python, flask, pyqt

I am using python 3.8 and flask. I tried to make a python browser app in python using QtWebEngine. It worked but, there was a bug it would open two windows at a time. I tried to fix it, by logging the number of times the window opened and check when to open the window, but there was some problem with opening the file.

Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStatusBar, QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys 
import os
import threading

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

port = 5000
windowName, url = 'IE', f'http://localhost:{port}/web/amazon'

class HtmlFile(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        open('running.log', 'a')
        file = open('running.log', 'r').read()
        if file == '0':
            if self.url != None:
                super(HtmlFile, self).__init__() 
                qurl = QUrl(self.url) 
                browser = QWebEngineView() 
                browser.setUrl(qurl) 
                self.setCentralWidget(browser) 
                self.status = QStatusBar() 
                self.setStatusBar(self.status) 
        else:
            file = open('running.log', 'w')
            file.write('0')

def run():
    global start
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    app.setApplicationName(windowName) 
    window = HtmlFile(url) 
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
thread.start()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["nm"]
        return redirect(url_for("user", usr=user))
    else:
        return render_template("getpost.html")

@app.route("/verifylogin", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def verifylogin():
        user = request.form["nm"]
        return redirect(url_for("user", usr=user))

@app.route("/usr/<usr>")
def user(usr):
    return f"<h1>Hello {usr}</h1>"

@app.route('/web/<open_website>')
def open(open_website):
    return render_template('index.html', open_website=open_website)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

EDIT: I fixed it. The debug parameter should be set to False

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The debug parameter should be set to False